# Use of a Structure instead of a Class in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I learn **Swift** from some time, I know the differences between structure and class. The main difference is structure is of value type and class is of reference type but didn't understand when to use structure instead of a class. Please explain it.

For example, In case of Protocols:

First, We have just a protocol of struct type:

```
protocol SomeProtocol{
    func doSomeStuff()
}
```

Second, We make protocol of class type like this:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class{
    func doSomeStuff()
}
```

So, Please explain me, when we have to use protocol of struct type or of class type.

Comment: You're mixing things. _class_ in your example just says that the protocol can be adopted by classes only. Nothing else and it has nothing to do with struct vs class. Search SO for struct vs classes, already asked many times or [read Mike's Friday Q&A](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-07-17-when-to-use-swift-structs-and-classes.html). And also you should read [Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly structs are passed by value (copied), and a class is passed by reference (copied just the memory address to the object).You may want to use structs for simpler types, because you get a free init for all the properties your struct has.And with protocols, the first one you can use it on class,struct and enum, the second you say that you only use that on classes,and you may want to put class if your protocol is a delegate or a data source,because you want the property(of the type of your protocol) weak to avoid the memory cycle. IMHO use classes for multi-scene apps because you don't need to take care to update value when you edited something in an another scene.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol is not "of struct type" or "of class type", that is wrong terminology.

If you write `SomeProtocol: class` you make sure only classes can conform to that protocol, structs cannot. If you don't include the `class` both classes and structs can conform.

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267) (scroll down to "Class-Only Protocols") tell you that

> You can limit protocol adoption to class types (and not structures or enumerations) by adding the `class` keyword to a protocol’s inheritance list. The class keyword must always appear first in a protocol’s inheritance list, before any inherited protocols.
>
> Use a class-only protocol when the behavior defined by that protocol’s requirements assumes or requires that a conforming type has reference semantics rather than value semantics. For more on reference and value semantics, see Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types and Classes Are Reference Types.